# How to switch from yaml to php config in symfony3?

Tags: symfony

In symfony 2.6 as i remember you could specify php config preference while installing symfony, but now it's yaml by default... There is also no entry in the symfony documentation about this matter.

Comment: You should just name it `config.php` and remove `config.yml` AFAIK [see docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/configuration_organization.html)

Comment: I could do that, but what about existing configuration data in config.yaml? One way to do that would be to go through each component in the docs and learn how to configure in php, but that will be waste of time.

Comment: What's the use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to move everything to php you could set the configuration file to `.php` rather than `.yml` like

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    // ...

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.php');
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep what you currently have and just use `php` for some of your configuration you could include it as an import like

```
# app/config/config.yml
imports:
    - { resource: 'parameters.yml' }
    - { resource: 'security.yml' }
    - { resource: 'your_config.php' }
```